# Proving that reads from an array are initialised in SPARK

Tags: ada

Given a very simple SPARK function that sums an array of integers:

```
function Add (X, Y : in Ints) return Ints is
   Sum : Ints;
begin
   for i in Ints'Range loop
      pragma Loop_Invariant (for all j in Ints'First .. i - 1 => Sum(j) = X(j) + Y(j));  -- line 7
      Sum(i) := X(i) + Y(i);
   end loop;

   return Sum;  -- line 11
end Add;
```

(Where `type Ints is array (Integer range 0 .. 9) of Integer_32`)

Compiling without the loop invariant works fine (because I have a precondition that bounds the elements of `X` and `Y` such that overflow cannot occur). However, I need the invariant in order to show some properties of the post condition, but it results in:

```
7:69: warning: "Sum" may be referenced before it has a value
Phase 2 of 3: analysis and translation to intermediate language ...
7:10: "Sum" is not initialized
11:7: warning: "Sum" might not be initialized
```

I'm not sure how the concept of "being initialised" is expressed in the proof language so I don't know how to convince gnatprove that no uninitialised reads are occuring.

I can remove the warnings by explicitly setting all the elements of `Sum` to zero at the start of the function but I'm hoping that there's a better way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SPARK, arrays are considered as entire objects, and a component-by-component initialization like you do is not allowed. However, there is a heuristics in gnatprove which allows a simple for-loop over the range of the array, as you do. This is why without a loop invariant, you don't get the warning. This heuristics breaks down with the loop invariant, that's why you get the warning again.

You will have to accept the warning using pragma Warnings, as described here:

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_rm/Pragma-Warnings.html

And to avoid the *error* you are getting at line 7, you may move the loop invariant after the assignment (and change the range of the quantificaton accordingly).